# Execute a bash script from the command line which requires an argument with spaces in

Tags: bash, terminal

I am attempting to execute a bash script from the command line. 
Sometimes it will require an argument that contains spaces.

```
bash test.sh -l "path/to/image/may contain spaces.png"
```

What is the correct way to provide this? I have tried escaping `\` but to no avail.

I receive the following error;

```
 bash splash.sh -b \#\000000 -l \"img/Rev Logo.jpg\"
    convert: unable to open image ''"img/Rev'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3093.
```

Which relates to this bit of code;

```
logo="$1"

if checkBackground -eq 1
        then 
        convert -size $size canvas:$back -background $back $tmp01
fi

convert \'$logo\' -background $back $tmp02

composite $tmp02 -gravity center $tmp01 output.jpg
```

Comment: Either double quoting the argument or using `\\` is appropriate.  If your attempts are failing, perhaps the script is not properly quoting its use of the arguments.  More detail (eg, code samples of test.sh) is needed.

Comment: I have just updated my question with additional information and code sample. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first argument to the script is "foo bar", then this line:

```
convert \'$logo\' -background $back $tmp02
```

is passing as its first argument to `convert` the string `'foo` and passing the second argument `bar'`.  You probably don't want that.  Change that line to:

```
convert "$logo" -background "$back" "$tmp02"
```

In general, double quote any variables.

And when you invoke the script, just quote the argument.  If you call the script as:

```
bash splash.sh -b \#\000000 -l \"img/Rev Logo.jpg\"
```

then you are passing two separate arguments: `"img/Rev` and `Logo.jpg"`.  It is perfectly valid to have a filename with a double quote in it, but very unusual.  If you want to pass the single argument `img/Rev Logo.jpg`, you want to invoke your script as:

```
bash splash.sh -b "#000000" -l "img/Rev Logo.jpg"
```

or

```
bash splash.sh -b \#000000 -l img/Rev\ Logo.jpg
```